# Spark convert PairRDD to RDD

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, java-pair-rdd

What is the best way to convert a PairRDD into an RDD with both K and V are merged (in java)?

For example, the PairRDD contains K as some string and V as a JSON. I want to add this K to the value JSON and produce an RDD.

**Input PairRDD**

```
("abc", {"x:"100", "y":"200"})
("def", {"x":"400", "y":"500")
```

**Output should be and RDD as follows**

```
({"x:"100", "y":"200","z":"abc"})
({"x":"400", "y":"500","z":"def"})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map to translate between the two
consider:

```
scala> pairrdd.foreach(println)
(def,Map(x -> 400, y -> 500))
(abc,Map(x -> 100, y -> 200))
```

(I think that's what your sample is meant to represent)

```
scala> val newrdd = prdd.map(X=> X._2 ++ Map("z"-> X._1))
scala> newrdd.foreach(println)
Map(x -> 100, y -> 200, z -> abc)
Map(x -> 400, y -> 500, z -> def)
```

You'll have to change the `val newrdd` to java syntax, but the right side of the equation (I believe) will stay the same